# How to include one html file in an html with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My main html page is given below index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

        <h1>AngulAir</h1>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="airport in airports">
                <a href="" ng-click="setAirport(airport.code)">{{airport.code}}-{{airport.city}}</a>
                -<a href="" ng-click="editAirport(airport.code)">Edit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p ng-show="currentAirport">currentAirport:{{currentAirport.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <p ng-show="editing.name"><input type="text" ng-model="editing.name" value=""/></p>
        <div ng-include="sidebyURL"></div>
        <div ng-include="formURL"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am using javascript file as given below app.js which present inside js/controllers folder

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.airports = {
        "PDX" : {
            "code" : "PDX",
            "name" : "Portland International Airport",
            "city" : "Portland",
            "destinations" : [ "LAX", "SFO" ]
        },
        "STL" : {
            "code" : "STL",
            "name" : "Lampbert-St. Louis International Airport",
            "city" : "St. Louis",
            "destinations" : [ "LAX", "MKE" ]
        },
        "MCI" : {
            "code" : "MCI",
            "name" : "Kansas City International Airport",
            "city" : "Kansas City",
            "destinations" : [ "SFO", "LAX" ]
        },
    };

    $scope.currentAirport=null;
    $scope.sidebyURL='partials/airport.html';
    $scope.formURL='partials/form.html';
    $scope.setAirport = function(code) {
        $scope.currentAirport = $scope.airports[code];
    };
    $scope.editAirport = function(code) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.airports[code];
    };

}
```

and I am including 2 html files in the main index.html file that 2 files airport.html is

```
<div ng-show="currentAirport">
    <h3>{{currentAirport.name}}</h3>
    <h4>Destinations</h4>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="destination in currentAirport.destinations">
            {{destination}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and another form.html is

```
<div ng-show="editing">
    <h3>Edit Airport</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="editing.name" value=""/>
</div>
```

and my 2 remaining html files are present in the folder partials and while executing index.html I am not able to include form.html and airport.html inside index.html file if you have any idea about these let me know thank you.....

Comment: is there any error in console? which angular version you are using? try `$scope.sidebyURL='/partials/airport.html';`

Comment: You can built your own custom directive to achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually set `scope.editing` and `scope.currentAirport` so the `ng-show` returns true? I've copied and pasted your code to plunker and works as expected

```
List: <button ng-repeat="airport in airports" ng-click="setAirport(airport.code)">{{airport.code}}</button>
    Edit: <button ng-repeat="airport in airports" ng-click="editAirport(airport.code)">{{airport.code}}</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wQt5wrTkE8YXwOaKacBq

Comment: k, its working in plunker but its not working using eclipse can you please check it in eclipse thank you

Comment: sorry, i'm a `WebStorm` user